# How to combine random effect and nested random effect with lme

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

I'm doing a mixed linear model. And I have subjects who have been select in 20 schools. So I want to take this to account.

For this, I want to put a random intercept for the "SCHOOL" variable and a random intercept and slope for my "SUBJECT". But I want to take into account the nested effect.

Does this code fit the nested model:

```
 lme(Y ~ T + X, random = list(SCHOOL = ~ 1, SUBJECT = ~ T), method = "ML")
```

`T` is the time, and `Y` the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

This code specifies that `SUBJECT` is nested within `SCHOOL`, and that for `SCHOOL` you have random intercepts, and for `SUBJECT` random intercepts and random slopes.

You could also fit the model with restricted maximum likelihood that provides better estimates for the variance components in small samples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume it's correct so. 

Small samples correspond to an effective of less of 100 ? My sample is constituate of about 600 subjects ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in package NLME, but with LME4 you could do it with:

```
lmer(y ~ t + x + (1 + T|SUBJECT:SCHOOL), REML = FALSE)
```